# C# Interface Class Question Cannot See Method

Tags: c#, class, interface, ilist

```
public interface IGroups
{
    IList<Group> GetGroups(UserGroup usrGrp);
}

public class GetUsrGrps : IGroups
{
    public IList<Group> GetGroups(UserGroup usrGroup)
    {
        List<Group> grps = new List<Group>();
        UserGroupDao UsrGrpDao = new UserGroupDao();
        DbDataReader ddr = UsrGrpDao.GetUserGroups(usrGroup);
        if (ddr.HasRows)
        {
            while (ddr.Read())
            {
                Group grp = new Group();
                grp.GroupId = Convert.ToInt32(ddr["groupId"]);
                grps.Add(grp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Group grp = new Group();
            grp.GroupId = Convert.ToInt32("0");
            grps.Add(grp);
        }
        return grps;
    }
}



 public UserGroup GetUser(UserGroup usrGrp)
    {

        UserGroupDao usrGroupDao = new UserGroupDao();
        DbDataReader ddr = usrGroupDao.GetUser(usrGrp);
        if (ddr.HasRows)
        {
            while (ddr.Read())
            {
                usrGrp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(ddr["id"]);
                usrGrp.FirstName = Convert.ToString(ddr["firstname"]);
                usrGrp.LastName = Convert.ToString(ddr["lastname"]);
                usrGrp.UserName = Convert.ToString(ddr["username"]);
            }
        }
        usrGrp.UserGroups = GetUsrGrps.GetGroups(usrGrp);
        return this;
    }

usrGrp.Groups is defined as IList<Group>...?  }
```

**usrGrp.UserGroups = GetUsrGrps.GetGroups(usrGrp); < -- Intellisense does not see the Method.  I get 'An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method or property
'GetUsrGrps.GetGroups(UserGroup)' ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to abandon the IGroups interface, and mark the method as static. Since this is just a database access object anyway, it makes sense for this to be a static method.

If you want to keep the interface, then you will have to instantiate an object.

```
usrGrp.UserGroups = (new GetUsrGrps).GetGroups(usrGrp);
```

Comment: @Jeff Yates - You’re probably right. I must be a very disturbed individual! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`GetGroups` is an instance method. Mark it with the `static` keyword or create an instance of its containing class and reference the method from that instance. Considering that the method, `GetGroups` is part of the interface, I would recommend going the instance route so that your class definition still matches the interface contract.

Comment: In which case it will no longer be considered to implement the interface.

Comment: @Lasse: Editing for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because GetGroups is not a static method on GetUsrGrps.

You would either need to declare it as static or create a new instance of GetUsrGrps to call the GetGroups method.

Answer (score 0):

Your method isn't static or your class is not instantiated.

You need to create an instance of the class like:

```
var getUsrGrps = new GetUsrGrps();
```

then change

```
usrGrp.UserGroups = GetUsrGrps.GetGroups(usrGrp);
```

to

```
usrGrp.UserGroups = getUsrGrps.GetGroups(usrGrp);
```

**OR**

change

```
public IList<Group> GetGroups(UserGroup usrGroup)
```

to

```
public static IList<Group> GetGroups(UserGroup usrGroup)
```

It looks like either will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be just

```
usrGrp.UserGroups = GetGroups(usrGrp);
```

The compiler thinks you're trying to call a static method, which GetGroups is not

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
 IGroups groups = new GetUsrGrps();
 usrGrp.UserGroups = groups.GetGroups(usrGrp);
```

You are currently calling it as if it were static, but it seems that your intention is to access it through the `IGroups` interface.